# Use different symbol for jQuery then $

Tags: javascript, razor

Is it possible to have 2 jQuery libraries in one page, but with different versions? Some controls which i found in google seems to be historicaly old and uses version 0.x - 1.x, but i also have bootstrap which requires version 2.x. Any Ideas?

Comment: If you want to use $ for something else than jQuery namespace, you should have a look at noconflict API https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Given jQuery's standing and it's user base, it is _very_ improbable that the source of the error you've discovered is the underlying cause. I'd recommend you check once again with this in mind and use the appropriate tools like a JS debugger (comes for free with decent browsers like chrome and ff) set watchpoints and breakpoints appropriately.

Comment: i use devexpress pivot grid control, it uses callbacks, it fill `$` with alot of datas it requires itself, and my events, properties dont work after him

Comment: If you can, I'd recomend being strict with the use of `$` when you use jQuery. Of course this is only a suggestion. One convention I find good is to use `$variablename` for jQuery objects like `var $elem = $('#some_id');`, clearly showing that this is an jQuery object. On other variables one does not use `$` prefix. Only as a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 
 [**jQuery.noConflict()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Ex:

```
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    // Do something with jQuery
   j( "div p" ).hide();
```

Comment: can i do something like this `var $headerFuncs = $;`? so i could use one variable for mouse events, other for documen.events? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, use `var $headerFuncs = jQuery.noConflict();`